# Combine multi-row array into single row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to combine the multi-row results of a `QUERY` into a single row.

The first result (A4:L4) should remain as-is with the following result added to the end of the previous result in the same row keeping blank values in place.  The header will be removed, so that doesn't need to be considered.

I've tried nesting `QUERY` and `FILTER` but am only managing to get a single column or transpose the whole array.

```excel
=QUERY({journeySquads!A:M},"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&A1&"'",1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use flatten (no restriction on string length)

```
=transpose(query(flatten(query(A2:M,"select * where A='test'"))," select Col1 where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom! I was unaware of `FLATTEN`

Comment: Google seem to be doing their best to keep it a secret ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out...

```excel
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("| ",,QUERY({journeySquads!A2:M},"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&A1&"'",0)),"|")
```